# Switching states when button is clicked?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, user-experience

I'm stuck with a design/UX issue that I'm working on.

I have a button which says "No Filter" and if I click, I want it to change to "Reset" and clicking on reset should get me back to old state. (No filter) (Additionally, I'm changing the value in the dropdown if that helps)

**What should I use to represent this behavior? (Switch, Button?) Kinda confused.**

Code:

```
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" id="removeDwell">
          <i id="removeDwell"></i> No filter
      </button>
```

[image]

Comment: If you're just switching between two states, you might find that a checkbox is a better option, and there are Bootstrap plugins for styling those, such as http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

Comment: @TiesonT. Yep agreed. I have tried this but am not convinced with switch. Is there anyway to do this with a button? (Like clicking the button will change the text on the button to "reset" with a different color?) .. Need inputs here please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest placing the both the button internal options in there at the start. Then use CSS and JS to toggle a class that hide/shows the relevant internals. Given that you mention you're changing the value inside the dropdown, i would assume you've probably already got a button `.on('click')` binding somewhere, this code would just extend that.

By using the `.btn-active-toggle` and the internal `.when-active` or `.when-inactive` classes, you have the option to use this same logic in a number of places that you'd like to toggle the internal display of a button (or rather anything with the class of `.btn-active-toggle`). In terms of naming conventions, given bootstrap includes CSS for any `.btn` with the class `.active`, you may want to consider using a different class name than `.active` if you do not wish for this out-of-the-box styling; just update the JS and CSS below.

*Note: this solution is not the best from an accessibility point of view, as screen readers will read both internals, without knowing which is active. If this is important for you, consider similarly toggling [aria values to specify which is active](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties)*

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-active-toggle" id="removeDwell">
    <span class="when-active">  
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No filter
    </span>
    <span class="when-inactive">    
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> Reset
    </span>
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-active-toggle.active .when-active,
.btn-active-toggle .when-inactive{
    display:inline-block;
}
.btn-active-toggle.active .when-inactive,
.btn-active-toggle .when-active{
    display:none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#removeDwell').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/t9ocoe46/)**

Comment: I think you can shorten the CSS by using `.btn-active-toggle.active .when-inactive,
.btn-active-toggle:not(.active) .when-active{
 display:none;
}`

Comment: @MichaelCoker, good point, however, for the small space it saves, id rather not have to worry about [IE7/8 supporting `:not`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3). If OP doesnt care about browsers that old (and i cant blame them), id encourage your code :)

Answer (score 0):

The following is a JavaScript solution which does not increase any HTML overhead:

```js
    var defaultText,
        substituteText,
        btn;

    /* Default text of the button */
    defaultText = 'No Filter';
    /* Alternate text for button */
    substituteText = 'Reset';
    /* Grab our button */
    btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

    /* Add a listener to the button instance so we can manipulate it */
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      changeText(this, defaultText, substituteText);
    }, false);

    /**
     * Change the text of a button
     * @param {el} object HTMLElement: button to change text of
     * @param {dText} string: default text
     * @param {nText} string: new text
     **/
    function changeText(el, dText, nText) {
      var content = '',
          context = '';
  
      /**
       * Set the text of a button
       *     - dependant upon current text
       **/
      function setText() {
        return (content === dText) ? nText : dText;
      }
  
      /* Check to see if the browser accepts textContent */
      if ('textContent' in document.body) {
        context = 'textContent';
        /* Get the current button text */
        content = el[context];
      /* Browser does NOT use textContent */
      } else {
        /* Get the button text with fallback option */
        content = el.firstChild.nodeValue;
      }
  
      /* Set button text */
      if (context === 'textContent') {
        el.textContent = setText();
      } else {
        el.firstChild.nodeValue = setText();
      }
    }
```

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 6em;
  height: 2em;
  padding: 0 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em ;
  margin: 3% 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #eee; 
  background-color: #1B6CBD;
  border: 1px solid #0E3A59;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #0E3A59,
    0 0 2px rgba(#1B6CBD, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 0.05em 0.05em 0 #555;

} 

.btn,
.btn:hover {
  transition: background 150ms;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:active { 
  color: #eee; 
  background: #114C8F;
  border-color: #0E3A59;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" type="button">No Filter</button>
```